# Super-Resolution software

Tags: image-processing

Superresolution (SR) is a class of techniques that enhance the resolution of an imaging system.

Is there any implementation of [these algorithms](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html) available?

I've tried, and found the following all unsatisfactory:

- QE Super Resolution 5b
- Perfect Resize 8.1
- Photo Acute 3

Comment: I'm looking for that too. Currently the camera on Oppo Find 7 and Oppo N3/R5 also use this technique to capture an image of resolution 50/64MP

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superresolution

Comment: Where is your list of requirements? Where do these three not match these requirements?

Comment: yes, all of them give lower quality than the link above (cyan button).

Comment: Please list the algorithms in your post rather than just linking to them. To avoid Link rot.

Comment: *They did not name the algorithm..

Comment: If you want this question re-opened, please answer these easy questions: 1) Do you have one source image, or several images of the same thing taken at the exact same angle? 2) Do you want an implementation of the exact algorithm used by http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~vision/SingleImageSR.html or is any upsampling algorithm OK? 3) Do you need a library or a webapp or an app or desktop software or a plugin? 4) If a library for what programming language, if an app for what OS, if a plugin for what software?

Comment: 5) What is your budget? 6) What exactly was wrong with the software you tried? (please give detailed reasons for each of the 3)

Comment: Photo Acute worked, but is no longer developed? https://www.photoacute.com/studio/order.html

Comment: @endolith: This question is closed. Feel free to post one or several questions, but be sure to address all of the questions asked in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also looking for some free software (on Windows, Linux or Android) or Photoshop plugin but the only ones I found that are free are Matlab programs. Those cannot run alone unless you converted the Matlab files to executable files.

## [Super-resolution Software](https://decsai.ugr.es/pi/superresolution/software.html)

> We have developed a Matlab program with graphical user interface that implements several image super-resolution methods developed in this project.
>
> This application is availabe for the use of researchers and companies.

[image: matlab superresolution]

---

## [Super-Resolution](http://lcav.epfl.ch/software/superresolution)

> Super-Resolution is a Matlab program with graphical user interface that implements several image registration and reconstruction algorithms for super-resolution imaging.
>
> This program is distributed under the General Public Licence GPL, which is included in the GPL file with the code.

---

Most remaining softwares I found are for videos since each frame only differs a tiny amount and the software can combine multiple consecutive images into a sharper video or snapshot of the video.

## [MDSP Resolution Enhancement Software](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~milanfar/software/superresolution.html)

> This is a Matlab-based software package for resolution enhancement from video, developed at the Multi-Dimensional Signal Processing (MDSP) research lab at the University of California at Santa Cruz, led by Peyman Milanfar.
>
> The main objective of this software tool is the implementation of several superresolution techniques. In particular, the techniques described in [1](http://www.lawyerment.com/downloads/Video_and_Audio/DVD_and_Video/Other_Video_Tools/Review_18948_index.htm), [2], [3], and several references therein are included. The techniques implemented cover robust methods, dynamic color superresolution methods, and simultaneous demosaicing and resolution enhancement.
>
> Some specific features of the software package are:
>
> - As part of this software package, motion estimation is done automatically by the program, or independently estimated motion vectors may be provided by the user.
> - The user is able to specify the region of interest to be processed.
> - A basic tracking algorithm is incorporated in the program so that if only a certain part of the input images are important for the user (a car moving in a crowded street), this region can be tracked and another data sequence containing only that particular object is produced.
> - The parameters of the imaging system (such as the point-spread function) may be specified by the user.
> - The input image files may be given as .mat (Matlab data file) or .avi format.
> - The output generated by the program can be .mat (Matlab data file) or .avi format.
> - Producing color or grayscale output images are optional, given color input frames.
> - For purposes of experimentation, the software package is capable of producing simulated video data for different imaging scenarios from a single high resolution input image, with user-controlled parameters.

[image: screenshot]

---

## [SuperResolution 1.0](http://www.lawyerment.com/downloads/Video_and_Audio/DVD_and_Video/Other_Video_Tools/Review_18948_index.htm)

> This trial-ware uses the same technique to upscale video resolution. You may extract the frame later, after up-scaling easily.
>
> Video upsizing plug-in for Adobe After Effects 6.5+ and Adobe Premiere Pro 2.0. Uses information from neighbor frames to upsize current frame. It provides more details than any known upsize method. Now you can convert SD video to HD!
>
> The plugin contains two modes of super-resolution and a Lanczos resize method which can serve as a fast high-quality replacement for bicubic resize. All modes give much sharper and detailed video than built-in scale transform.
>
> The upsize method used in this plugin works only with progressive video (not interlaced). The plugin can also be used to downsize video with good quality.
>
> You may use this free trial as long as you want. Unregistered version adds watermark over the video. Register to turn off the watermark.

---

Another similar software is *vReveal* but it seems the main page has been down

[image: vReveal]

- [Video super-resolution coming to consumer software](http://www.megaleecher.net/Fix-Shaky-Videos-And-Enhance-Quality-With-Single-Click.htm)
- [vReveal - Free Video Enhancement Software To Fix Dark, Shaky, Blurry And Low-Resolution Videos](http://xcorr.net/2011/09/15/video-super-resolution-coming-to-consumer-software/)

---

## [SuperResolution plugin](http://superresolution-plugin.soft112.com/)

[image: super resolution plugin]

> Video upsizing plug-in for Adobe After Effects and Premiere Pro (CS5, CS6, CC 2014 - 2015). Uses information from neighbor frames to upsize current frame. It provides more details than any known upsize method. Now you can convert SD video to HD! The plugin contains two modes of super-resolution and a Lanczos resize method which can serve as a fast high-quality replacement for bicubic resize. All modes give much sharper and detailed video than built-in scale transform. The upsize method used in this plugin works only with progressive video (not interlaced). The plugin can also be used to downsize video with good quality.
>   You may use this free trial as long as you want. Unregistered version adds watermark over the video. Register to turn off the watermark.
>
> SuperResolution plugin is a free trial software application from the Video Tools subcategory, part of the Audio & Multimedia category. The app is currently available in English and it was last updated on 2016-08-11. The program can be installed on Windows 7, Windows8, WinVista, WinVista x64, WinXP, Win10 x64, Win8 x64, Windows 8, Windows 10.

A similar question on photography.SE: [Is there a photoshop plugin or any other piece of software that can do super resolution?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/24495/25588)

Comment: I'm also interested in Linux applications, if anyone found one, please suggest

Comment: Please split into one answer per app, and make sure each answer has everything described at http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I can't split it because the question has been closed

Comment: OK, waiting for Kokizzu to fix the question based on my comments.